# PHP sem_get() results in "Permission denied"

Tags: php, selinux

The sem_get method always throws. What can be the cause of this issue?

We are running a centos server with php-fpm and selinux. The audit.log does not contain any information about this particular error.

Does the sem_get store the semaphores on disk?

Update:
The sem_get method works if called via cli

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sem-get.php has a warning about creating the semaphore outside of PHP. Also it might help others if you show your actual function call, and the parameters you're passing.

Comment: Thanks, but the semaphore is created within php.

Comment: It will still help to show actual code. People might be able to spot an error in how you're creating/accessing it.

Comment: It is only a function call, nothing more.

Comment: A function call with parameters. =) Anyway, the fact it works via CLI does suggest that it's disk access-based since your user account may have different permissions from the web server account